# Is it possible to show two active indexes for a multiview at a time

Tags: asp.net, multiview

I am having a multiview with

```
  Activeviewindex=-1.
```

I will have some views assume 3. In one view i will have a grid view placed and the other 2 views contain some controls. Now initially i will load the view with grid view now if the user clicks on radio button available in the grid view i would like to show the corresponding view along with grid view. But as per my thinking we can only show one view at a time. so is there any possibility to show 2 views of multiview at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off placing your controls inside of `<asp:Panel>` controls and conditionally showing or hiding different panels in your code-behind.  You can then show two at once, with the caveat that when you want to switch views, you have to manually hide all previously showing panels.

Replace your existing `MultiView`:

```
<asp:MultiView ... >
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server"> ... </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server"> ... </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server"> ... </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

With a series of `Panel`s:

```
<asp:Panel ID="View1" runat="server"> ... </asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="View2" runat="server"> ... </asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="View3" runat="server"> ... </asp:Panel>
```

And show or hide them as needed:

```
// switch to Panel #3
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    View1.Visible = false;
    View2.Visible = false;
    View3.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I used panels inside the views too. But i am unable to load 2 views at a time

Comment: I meant to replace the `Multiview` with a collection of `Panel`s.

Comment: But for one view one panel so as per you are saying in a view use 2 panels and show both

Comment: @Dorababu: Why not leave the `GridView` out of the `MultiView` entirely?

Comment: Oh then it will be tricky for me then  i should have around 15 panels

Comment: @Dorababu: If all of the other views in the `MultiView` except the `GridView` should be shown one at a time, but sometimes the `GridView` should be shown at the same time as another view, then I would just take the `GridView` out of the `MultiView` and manually show/hide it as necessary.

Comment: Oh inside multiview i have to use Panel instead of views

Comment: Ya but my form look and feel worst with huge spaces and all so i would like to have my grid view inside a view

Comment: @Dorababu: Not sure I understand.  The view is just a container, it doesn't render anything on the page.

Comment: ya actually i am having 2 multiview as per you said if i place the gridview out side the view while showing 2nd multiview the space that occupied by gridview will remain as empty space right so in order to remove that i would like to have my gridview inside multiview

Comment: @Dorababu: You can set `GridView.Visible = false;` while the `GridView` is not in use.  It has the same effect as being located in a view that is currently not the active index for a `MultiView`.  Then it would render nothing at all in the page.

Comment: so means in multiview1 i would like to replace all views with a panel and in one panel i have to make my gridview while showing multiview2 as multiview1 active index will be hidden the same place will be occupied by multiview2 right

Comment: @Dorababu: Roughly, yes.  In my example, the `Panel` completely replaces the `View` and `MultiView`.  There is nothing to do with `MultiView` left whatsoever.  The `Panel` controls are not "contained" inside of anything.

Comment: @Dorababu: I would suggest trying it out and see what happens.

Comment: @Dorababu instead of setting visible fale and all that for multiple gridviews in page why don't you set the design of the page such that it automatically fits the page width... that is set the width on grid view instead of the gridview container... or there is one more option use ajax control toolkit's accordian/collapsible panel extender  =>http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Showing two View at a Time is not possible in `MultiView` instead you can use separate panels as mentioned by @mellamokb.
Also have a look at [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ek2z7fh)